# Debugging java code in Eclipse. Debugging buttons become blocked

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging the source code in Eclipse, I faced a strange problem. There is the following line in the code:

```
this.myObj = createMyObject();
```

where myObj is an instance of MyClass.

Once this line is executed, I move a cursor to `myObj` in order to see its content. The content is displayed correctly. But when I move a cursor to `myObj` for the second time (without doing anything else), the content disappears and it looks like the object has not been created. Moreover, the debugging buttons, such as `Step Into`, `Step Over`, etc. become unavailable (blocked).

Any thoughts?

**Edit#1**
This is the code that should be executed once pressing the button in Swing application. So, if I try to run the code in non-debug mode, then the application just stops responding after clicking the button.

**Edit#2**

The code snippet is the following. It looks like when I try to add more that 1 entry to `toks`, the code fails. What is the reason?

```
this.myObj = createMyObject();

public myObj createMyObject() {
  MyClass myObj = new MyClass();

  Col col = new Col(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
  ArrayList<Token> toks = new ArrayList<Token>();
  toks.add(new Token(col,new Integer[]{1,10,1,1,null,null,null,null}));
  toks.add(new Token(col,new Integer[]{2,11,2,1,null,null,null,null}));

  //...

  Place p = myObj.place(col,toks);

  //...
  return myObj;
}
```

Comment: is it reproducable?may be related to Eclipse by restarting may solve the problem.

Comment: I restarted Eclipse. Nothing has changed.

Comment: BTW, the code was executable. Then I updated the content of myObj (just added new values to object´s elements), and after this I faced this strange problem.

Comment: another attempt by recreating workspace

Comment: Do you mean i should create a new project and copy SRC files to it?

Comment: The funny thing is that if I undo changes and return to previous values of the object elements, then everything works fine.

Comment: it happens sometimes with eclipse

Comment: I tried to recreate the workspace. I did not help to solve the problem.

Comment: please post the source code in question after what changes it is working?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can be a little bit buggy sometimes and probably it's not a specific answer but these steps can be helpful:

1 - Backup your data.
2 - Uninstall Eclipse.
3 - Restart your computer
4 - Install the latest clean version of eclipse without unofficial plugins
5 - Restart your computer again.
6 - Try again.

Comment: After I completed all steps indicated in your post, the problem is partly solved, but it does not disappear completely. Now I can run the code if toks contains 2 entries. But if I add more entries it stops without printing an error message. The same in debug mode.

Comment: I need to restart Eclipse and my Genymotion's Android simulator. That fixed my problem. I think previously I was able to get the buttons enabled by switching between perspective (DDMS, Debug, etc).